# PowerBi Dax code to replicate excel sumif

Tags: powerbi, dax, percentage, sumifs, invoice

I am looking to calculate

'supplier = (sum of group 1 x weighting) + (sum of group 2 x weighting).

In excel I use 2 tables to calculate, but struggling to figure this out in powerbi so far

I am currently using PowerBi to create Averages of scores per supplier.

I am now trying to moved towards weighted totals and weighted averages.

In my scenario I have

```
8 Divisions
22 Groups (of suppliers ie. Joint Ventures, multiple Suppliers working on a contract)
8 Individual Suppliers made up of a percentage of a group of suppliers.
```

Within Excel, I have created a supplier list 1-8 which uses a sum if from another table.

```
SUMIFS('Group Totals (Per)'!F:F,'Group Totals (Per)'!$B:$B,$B2)
```

This other table is a sumif of group name, division multiplied by weighting (percentage of the contract)

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(Payments!$I:$I,Payments!$C:$C,'Group Totals'!$A7,Payments!$B:$B,'Group Totals'!F$1)*$C7)
```

My hope is to replicate this within power BI.

So I can click select a supplier and see the total payments received (which will be a sum of a percentage of the group contract (joint ventures).

However I have been unable to separate out the suppliers totals with weighting, after creating links tables.

I have supplied sample data in excel and power BI and screenshots.

Here's [a link](https://1drv.ms/f/s!Aqw9t5Hm7znwgbtHR_jg9iNKeZXR2w)! to the files.

Answer (score 0):

[SUMX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/sumx-function-dax) is similar to `SUMIF` in Excel. But I would recommend you using [CALCULATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/calculate-function-dax) function which gives you lot of options. A simple google will give you a lot of tutorials on how to use it.

Comment: Thanks I'll give a try, but could find any matching my criteria. I am looking to calculate 'supplier = sum of group 1 x weighting + sum of group 2 x weighting. In excel I use 2 tables to calculate, but struggling to figure this out in powerbi so far